# Calling Activity from WebView on shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: android-webview

In webview, I click a link that takes me to an activity through following code :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(url.equals("factory.cpp")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FactoryCppFiles.class) ;
            startActivity(intent) ;
            return false ;
        }
        else
            return true ;
    }
```

The FactoryCppFiles activity is displayed properly, but when I press the back button, it shows me the following standard error message.

> Web page not available

I want to show the web view where I clicked on the link. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just realized I should return true if I want to handle the URL myself. I switched the return statements and it works fine now.